# PHP fully escape quotes inside attribute

Tags: php

I want an confirmation message before going to the URL but havning problems escaping the quotes in the message.

Getting this error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 
Code: return confirm('Please confirm delete: 'iphone'');
```

When I var_dump the output its correctly converting the quotes to: `&#039;`

Test code here:

```
<?php

$text = 'Please confirm delete: \'%s\'';

$config_text = sprintf($text, 'iphone');

?>

<a href="" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $config_text; ?>');">Click 1</a>

<br /><a href="" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($config_text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>');">Click 2</a>

<br /><a href="" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo mb_convert_encoding($config_text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); ?>');">Click 3</a>
```

I know this sort of question has been asked lots of other times and likely to get closed but everything I have tried isn't working.

Comment: maybe `htmlspecialchars()` will work for you

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but no joy

Comment: `onclick="return confirm('<?php echo addslashes( ...  ); ?>');">Click</a>`

Comment: `Click1` will cause the syntax error, `Click2` should work, `Click3` I don't know, TBH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three Clicks should work fine with double quoted variable $text

```
$text = "Please confirm delete: \'%s\'";
```

You should see correct web page soure code like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('Please confirm delete: \'iphone\'');">Click 1</a>
<br /><a href="" onclick="return confirm('Please confirm delete: \&#039;iphone\&#039;');">Click 2</a>
<br /><a href="" onclick="return confirm('Please confirm delete: \'iphone\'');">Click 3</a>
```